# Are questions on using APIs of programs allowed?

Tags: support, questions, api

I am trying to make some upgrades to a NetBeans IDE plugin I published a while ago, one of the things I want to add is a sub-menu for it, however even after reading the API documentation I am not fully sure of how to fully use the sub-menu class. So I was wondering if this sort of question asking how to use a certain API in a program such as NetBeans IDE is allowed here?

Comment: Well, did you do some [research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Question+API)? Also the [tag:netbeans] tag is available, and your questions about their API should be allowed. Though don't miss to provide a MCVE where and why exactly you failed using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I was wondering if this sort of question asking how to use a certain API in a program such as NetBeans IDE is allowed here?

You may check first if your API question fits with the following points (taken from the [Help Center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)):

> > Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
> >
> > - a specific programming problem, or
> > - a software algorithm, or
> > - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> > - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

So yes, you can ask such questions about the [netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netbeans) [API](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bnetbeans%5dAPI) (note to add the mentioned tag).

Take care to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of how you tried to use the API and where and how exactly you are stuck in using it from your code.

Comment: As an aside, don't use the [[tag:api]]-tag on main, it's useless.